# Can I install Ubuntu on a PC with less than 2gb of ram

Tags: ram, dvd

I have a PC with 1.2GB of RAM (Windows says 756MB). I plan to get another 1GB stick of RAM, but for now, can I install Ubuntu even though I don't have the required 2GB of RAM? I'm using DVD to install and I chose to download the main Ubuntu version on the Ubuntu page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create create and activate large swap partition during installation but this is going to make the system slow unless you have a really fast hdd. LUbuntu is in my opinion a better option.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended for you to use Lubuntu - the official Ubuntu derived distribution which is specifically designed for low end hardware.